# Nuxt ..show 2 images from API in 1 div

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, slick.js, v-for

Hello im getting images from an API i can put them in a slick slider but i want too put 2 images from the API in the div that slick slide is creating .

Now in my Vue Slick:

```
<div :class="{ 'landscape': media.is_landscape, 'portrait': !media.is_landscape }"  v-for="media in talent_portfolio.medias" :key="media">

      <img fluid class="img-wrapper" :class="talent_portfolio.name" :src="media.url" />
        
   </div>
```

The Html Render :

```
<div data-v-e4caeaf8="" tabindex="-1" data-index="1" aria-hidden="false" class="slick-slide slick-active slick-center slick-current" style="outline: none; width: 1593px;">

<div data-v-e4caeaf8="">
<div data-v-e4caeaf8="" tabindex="-1" class="portrait" style="width: 100%; display: inline-flex;">
<img data-v-e4caeaf8="" fluid="" src="https://######" class="img-wrapper">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**And i try to have for make my slick layout :**

```
 <div data-v-e4caeaf8="" tabindex="-1" data-index="1" aria-hidden="false" class="slick-slide slick-active slick-center slick-current" style="outline: none; width: 1593px;">
    
    <div data-v-e4caeaf8="">
    <div data-v-e4caeaf8="" tabindex="-1" class="portrait" style="width: 100%; display: inline-flex;">
    <img data-v-e4caeaf8="" fluid="" src="https://######" class="img-wrapper"> (image 1 from API)
    <img data-v-e4caeaf8="" fluid="" src="https://######" class="img-wrapper"> (image 2 from API)
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<div data-v-e4caeaf8="" tabindex="-1" data-index="1" aria-hidden="false" class="slick-slide slick-active slick-center slick-current" style="outline: none; width: 1593px;">

<div data-v-e4caeaf8="">
<div data-v-e4caeaf8="" tabindex="-1" class="portrait" style="width: 100%; display: inline-flex;">
<img data-v-e4caeaf8="" fluid="" src="https://######" class="img-wrapper"> (image 3 from API)
<img data-v-e4caeaf8="" fluid="" src="https://######" class="img-wrapper"> (image 4 from API)
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Anyone can explain to me how to get 2 img by slide from APi ? Thank you everybody

Comment: What problem did you encounter?

Comment: My problem is for the slick layout i need two have 2 images sticky together but i cant find how to display 2 img from the API in 1 div for have them sticky

Comment: The thing you need to do is modify the data you receive from the API before using it in your templating. When The API call is done run a function that will adjust the structure of the data you receive to have it in the format you want. In your example, by putting two images in one object.

Comment: What does the API return? Could you show the structure of what it returns?

Comment: Hello the API return me like this : "medias":[{"id":4178121,"type":0,"is_landscape":false,"photographer":null,"designer":null,"hairdresser":null,"grooming":null,"make_up_artist":null,"manicure":null,"support_name":null,"brand":null,"link":null,"link_title":null,"url":"https:\/\/bucket-prod-0... so  i can get the images my  problem is when i show the images i cant remove the space between them